# Prompt User about Session Timeout and Extend Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session, iis

I want to prompt the user 1 minute before the Session Expires and Extend it when user clicks 'OK'. 
Currently, I have written an `ActionFilter` which checks for SessionTimeout and Redirects to a View in case Session Times out. I then decorate my controller with the `CheckSessionTimeOut` attribute.

```
public class CheckSessionTimeOutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var context = filterContext.HttpContext;
            if (context.Session != null)
            {
                if (context.Session.IsNewSession)
                {
                    string sessionCookie = context.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                    if ((sessionCookie != null) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                    //if (true)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                        var c = new HttpCookie("Cookie");
                        c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                        context.Response.Cookies.Add(c);
                        string redirectTo = "~/BundleDealer/SessionExpire";
                        context.Response.Redirect(redirectTo, true);


                    }
                }
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

What would be the best way to do the required?

Comment: i recently implement it by using jquery plugin on client side

Comment: @EhsanSajjad How can we do it with jquery? I mean we have session variables on server side. Can you share how you did it?

Comment: The client seems like the more logical place to do this. But I wonder about it from a security standpoint. Session timeout could be viewed as an additional line of defense in case someone leaves a computer logged in to a site. In that scenario, wouldn't this alert another user on the computer that the previous user was logged in to the site and give them the opportunity to stay logged in?

Comment: @HumaAli what i did was it trackes user inactivity and if user is inactive for 5 minutes prompts that after next more 5 minutes it will be auto logged out, if user does not click button it is logged out after 5 minutes

Comment: i used this plugin : https://github.com/thorst/jquery-idletimer